# Opening browser from cli with no menubar/location/etc

Tags: command-line

I have a desktop application that opens a tutorial, hosted on a website, when it runs for the first time.  I want the tutorial to open in a standard browser window minus the menubar/location bar etc...  In javascript this would be simple enough but I can't find any information on how to do it from the command line (if it's even possible).

I'm only concerned with Mac OS X so I'm happy with a solution that specifically addresses Safari but any info on other browsers would also be useful.

**UPDATE**

blahdiblah's solution only allows toggling of the toolbars.  With no info on what is currently open or closed, it isn't a very suitable solution.

Answer (score 1):

From [this blog post](http://macmembrane.com/toggle-fullscreen-kiosk-mode-in-safari-with-applescript/), do it with Applescript (and `osascript`):

```
tell application "Safari"
    activate
    if bounds of window 1 is not equal to {0, 22, 1440, 900} then
        tell application "System Events"
            keystroke "b" using {command down, shift down}
            keystroke "|" using command down
        end tell
        set bounds of window 1 to {0, 22, 1440, 900}
    else
        tell application "System Events"
            keystroke "b" using {command down, shift down}
            keystroke "|" using command down
        end tell
        set bounds of window 1 to {160, 80, 980, 700}
    end if
end tell
```

Read the post for additional information and caveats.

Comment: Actually, I've just realised this doesn't provide one off functionality as javascript does.  Once my window is closed, safari keeps the settings (i.e. the location bar, menubar,... remain hidden)

Comment: True, though you could always reverse the settings changes you'd made afterwards.

Comment: The problem is I don't know what settings the user is running with.  If they normally have the tab bar disabled, I might be opening it...  Sending the keystrokes is just a toggle which isn't so useful when you don't know the current state.